# Characteristic polynomial: Identity permutation?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

This concerns the characteristic polynomial of a matrix.

http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/num_/lnv.pdf p. 7 (or p. 92).

---

> every term is prescribed by a permutation π
>   of the rows of the
>   matrix

---

> identity permutation is obtained by multiplying the diagonal entries together

---

What is the identity permutation?

Comment: A permutation on $\;n\;$ objects is a bijection from these objects to themselves, and the identity permutation is just the identity function: $\;f(i)=i\;,\;\;\forall\,i\;$

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about eigenvalues or characteristic polynomials of   matrices, but the identity permutation is the permutation that keeps the order of everything the same. It's called the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics)) because that's the naming convention things that keep everything the same. For example, $0$ is the identity of addition and $1$ is the identity of multiplication.

Here's some examples of the identity permutation (I'm going to call the identity permutation here $\sigma$):
$$\sigma(123)=(123)$$
$$(12)\sigma(34)=(12)(34)$$